# Automate updates from Azure Function App to API Management

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-api-management

Given that Azure Functions can be imported to API Management [as described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-function-app-as-api), how do we keep the API up to date when Azure Functions change?  For example, if the Function signature changes or a function is added or removed. How can this process be automated, so once the Azure Functions change, the changes are reflected in the API?

Microsoft's API Management team has a [proposed solution here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit#azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit), but it's not clear to me how this solution can be applied with Azure Function App as the backed-end for the API.

Comment: So I can improve the question, when you downvote, please provide feedback as to why.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue 2 years on!!

Comment: @an0nc0d3r Unfortunately, we had to settle for manually adding/removing Azure functions to API Management :/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to make it as part of your release process. After publishing the new version of Azure Functions, you'll import the new specification into API Management.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stephane-eyskens.apim

Comment: Would you happen to know if there is good documentation on set up of this extension?  The only one I can find is on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/stephaneey/azure-apim-extension#setup-prerequisite-and-considerations) which doesn't go into details.

Comment: Please note that this extension is valid only for Azure Functions (v1).   See authors comment here - https://github.com/stephaneey/azure-apim-extension/issues/97#issuecomment-672823129

Comment: the extension is valid, the way functions generate the spec is the issue

Answer (score 1):

Once you import and publish an API in APIM **it will not be updated automatically**. So, even though the developers released a new build, the consumers would still consume the older version of the API published in APIM.

Try to use [Azure DevOps pipelines for continuous delivery of APIs to Azure API Management Service](https://mscloud.be/azure/Update-API-in-APIM-from-Azure-Devops/).

Add a create/update task, which will create or update the API in APIM based on the Swagger file and also set different API policies. This task will also update the API in APIM in case the Dev guy will create new API methods or remove API methods.

Comment: Thank you Joey. The article describes synching the build with API using an extension by Stephan Eyskens.  Unfortunately, in our case, this extension does not work.   We use Azure Functions v2.0 and extension is only compatible with v1.0.   See his comment https://github.com/stephaneey/azure-apim-extension/issues/98#issuecomment-671961620